# Passing the tuple by reference into lambda causes null pointer dereference warning

Tags: c++, lambda, pass-by-reference, compiler-warnings

I have the following piece of code:

```
boost::circular_buffer<std::tuple<float, float, float>> foo;
foo.push_front(std::make_tuple(3.1f, 1.5f, 1.2f));
foo.push_front(std::make_tuple(3.6f, 1.1f, 1.7f));
foo.push_front(std::make_tuple(3.2f, 1.1f, 1.9f));

const float bar = 3.5f;

// find the first tuple for which the first element is greater than bar
auto firstGreater = std::find_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [bar](const auto &t) {
    return std::get<0>(t) > bar;
});
```

When compiling this code with GCC version 7.5.0 or 9.3.0 (did not try with other versions) with a flag -Wnull-dereference, I get a warning in the return statement of the lambda:

```
error: potential null pointer dereference [-Werror=null-dereference]
139 |                         return std::get<0>(t) > bar;
    |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Interestingly enough, when the tuple is passed to the lambda by value instead of by reference, the warning is gone:

```
auto firstGreater = std::find_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [bar](auto t) {
    return std::get<0>(t) > bar;
});
```

I am trying to understand why that would be the case since a reference cannot point to nothing, but can't figure out the root of the issue. Any ideas why this might happen?

**Note**: the above snippet is just a sample, but it does reflect the essence of what is going on in the real code. Although it may not be enough to reproduce the warning

Comment: I can not reproduce it: https://godbolt.org/z/r8b71PWTT The cause may be more subtle than you expect. Please try to form a [mre].

Comment: I would say that it detects a possible deferencement of null pointer which is reported in your code.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, I assume so too, but where does the null pointer come from in the first place?

Comment: You have to inspect `boost::circular_buffer` implementation. I suspect that instead of nullptr check, there is another *"equivalent"* check (as `size != 0`) which makes the linter to fail.

Comment: Works just fine on my machine.  I don't think there is a bug in the code provided; I suspect the bug is somewhere else in the code not provided.  Bit odd to push_front onto `foo` that has a capacity of 0.  From Boost documentation "Warning Since Boost version 1.36 the behaviour of this constructor has changed. Now the constructor does not allocate any memory and both capacity and size are set to zero. Also note when inserting an element into a circular_buffer with zero capacity ... nothing will be inserted and the size (as well as capacity) remains zero."